# Universal windows phone app. Populate hubsection with DataTemplate programmatically

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I have my page with a `DataTemplate` like this:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="msgTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Titolo" Foreground="White" Margin="0,10,0,0" FontSize="20"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TITOLO}" x:Name="titolo" Foreground="White" Margin="0,0,0,0" FontStyle="Italic" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="25"/>

            <TextBlock Text="Descrizione" Foreground="White" Margin="0,10,0,0" FontSize="20"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DESCRIZIONE}" x:Name="descrizione" Foreground="White" Margin="0,0,0,0" FontStyle="Italic" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="25"/>

            <TextBlock Text="Priorità" Foreground="White" Margin="0,10,0,0" FontSize="20"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PRIORITA}" x:Name="priorita" Foreground="White" Margin="0,0,0,0" FontStyle="Italic" TextWrapping="Wrap"  FontSize="25"/>

            <TextBlock Text="Visibile dal:" Foreground="White" Margin="0,10,0,0" FontSize="20"/>
            <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding VISIBILE_DA_VISIBILITY}" Text="{Binding VISIBILE_DA}" x:Name="visibileDa" Foreground="White" Margin="0,0,0,0" FontStyle="Italic" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="25"/>

            <TextBlock Text="Visibile al:" Foreground="White" Margin="0,10,0,0" FontSize="20"/>
            <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding VISIBILE_A_VISIBILITY}" Text="{Binding VISIBILE_A}" x:Name="visibileA"  Foreground="White" Margin="0,0,0,0" FontStyle="Italic" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="25"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

This DataTemplate refers to this Hub:

```
    <Hub x:Name="Panorama" Grid.Row="1" Width="Auto" Loaded="Panorama_Loaded" SectionsInViewChanged="Panorama_SectionsInViewChanged" >

        <HubSection x:Name="section">
            <DataTemplate>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>

    </Hub>
```

My problem is how to bind my datas to populate this hubsection.
I want my app to automatically create `x` sections where `x` is the number of items in my list.

Here is my object

```
    class LSK_MSG
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public string TITOLO { get; set; }
        public string DESCRIZIONE { get; set; }
        public string VISIBILE_DA { get; set; }
        public string VISIBILE_A { get; set; }
        public string VISIBILE_DA_VISIBILITY { get; set; }
        public string VISIBILE_A_VISIBILITY { get; set; }
    }
```

And here I set my template to an hubsection I'm creating

```
        msgs = new MESSAGGIO().SelectAll();
        lskMsgs = new List<LSK_MSG>();
        maxIndex = msgs.Count;

        HubSection mHubSection;
        foreach (MESSAGGIO m in msgs)
        {
            mHubSection = new HubSection();
            mHubSection.Template = (ControlTemplate)App.Current.Resources["msgTemplate"];

            lskMsgs.Add(new LSK_MSG()
            {
                DESCRIZIONE = m.DESCRIZIONE,
                TITOLO = m.TITOLO,
                ID = m.ID,
                VISIBILE_DA = m.VISIBILE_DA == null ? "" : msg.VISIBILE_DA.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                VISIBILE_A = m.VISIBILE_A == null ? "" : msg.VISIBILE_A.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                VISIBILE_DA_VISIBILITY = m.VISIBILE_DA == null ? "Collapsed" : "Visible",
                VISIBILE_A_VISIBILITY = m.VISIBILE_A == null ? "Collapsed" : "Visible"
            });
            mHubSection.s
        }
```

The hub is initialized, my problem is: Now that I created an `hubsection`, and now that I set to it the `DataTemplate`. How can I set my "`LSK_MSG`" as the hubsection's content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pier Giorgio, you need to set `DataContext` of each HubSection to each object of itemlist. Since you are manually creating HubSection, for x items in list, x hubsection will be created. Also, you don't need new list lskMsgs. Just modify `foreach` loop. Let's say the name of your `Hub` control is testHubControl.

```
foreach(MESSAGIO m in msgs)
{
  mHubSection = new HubSection();
  mHubSection.ContentTemplate =(DataTemplate)this.Resources["msgTemplate"];
  mHubSection.DataContext = m;
  testHubControl.Sections.Add(mHubSection);
}
```

FYI, this code works as I have already tested it. So please mark this answer as correct answer. You can comment for any further queries.

Comment: thanks! I only have one question: I set my template inside the xaml of the page and I don't know if it's the right place. is it?

Comment: If you are using that Template only in that page, then you can set it inside that page's XAML. However, if you intend to use this template in multiple Pages, then I suggest you to add it in App.XAML.

Comment: mHubSection.Template =(ControlTemplate)App.Current.Resources["msgTemplate"]; is saing he can't find the resource :(

Comment: That's because, my dear you have declared the template in that Page's Xaml and not in App.xaml. Instead, write this--- (DataTemplate)this.Resources["msgTemplate"];    
Also, your casting is wrong. It should be DataTemplate.
Also, according to you, I have modified the previous answer that I posted

Comment: @RahulRanjan How about using a `ObservableCollection<T> Hubs` and inside this specify your `data template` and use `Binding` it will work fine.

Comment: @Eldho, It won't work because neither Hub control, nor HubSection has <Hub.ItemsTemplate> or <HubSection.ItemsTemplate>. So simple binding like ListView or GridView won't work. You have to manually create subsequent hubsection.

Comment: Thanks i dont have prior experience in that.